# $x * $y = $z is zero

Tags: php, math

I must transform an price from RON tu EUR ang I am getting `0` in my operation.

The code I've used:

```
  include('./panou/simple_html_dom.php');
  function euro() {
       $dom= file_get_html("http://www.cursvalutar.ro/");;  
       foreach ($dom->find('tr') as $node) {
       if (is_a($node->children(1), 'simple_html_dom_node')) {
            if ($node->children(1)->plaintext == "Euro") {
            $plain = explode(',', $node->children(2)->plaintext);           
         if(!isset($plain[0])!== false) {
                      echo("Nu are");
                  }
          elseif(stripos($plain[0], $plain[0])!== false{
                      "4.30"
                  }
             }
        }
   }
   $plain[0]*=$koyos; echo "$plain[0]";}
```

`$plain[0] = 4.3780` and `$koyos = 545.66` the result of script is `0`

Comment: Is this really a PHP code? If so then what's the reasoning behind `if(...){"4.30"}`? What's the point in creating and discarding a string literal if something is true? ... never mind the missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: because "why not?"

Comment: Contains a syntax error (visible after Cthulhu's edit). Close as too localised?

Comment: the reason of `4.3` is if price is not taked good, to use 4,3 Ron for euro transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, use this url for real value of RON-EUR: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=RONEUR=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv
Parse a CSV file is easier than a HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with code:
$koyos variable is not defined in the euro() function.
Pass it to the function.
If you want to print an element of an array you should do like this:

```
     echo $plain[0]
     echo "{$plain[0]}"    //  this two prints what you want
```

This is not good way:

```
     echo "$plain[0]"      // the result of this might be "Array[0]"
```

But better to replace your code with this:

```
    function getEuroRon(){
            if (!$file = fopen('http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=EURRON=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv','r')){
                    die('resource can not be read');
            }
            $data = fgetcsv($file);
            fclose($file);
            return $data[1];
    }
    $euroron = getEuroRon();
    /*
    //... somewhere in code:
    $koyos = 545.66;

    //i dont recommend to use global variables but you might need this:
    function euro(){
          global $koyos,$euroron;
          print $euroron * $koyos;
    }
    */
    //This should be better instead the previous:
    function euro($koyos){
          global $euroron;
          print $euroron * $koyos;
    }   
    euro(545.66);
```

And you can call euro() function where you need to print the result... 
There should be mutch better way , but i dont know the other details of your code and tried to solve your problem nearly same way as you coded.

Or you can use a little bit better solution:
http://pastebin.com/HMp8SR2j